# How to show error message for last duplicate value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show error message for last duplicate value in a table using jquery.table value i am adding dynamicaly.So how do it?. please share your ideas to resolve this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    var arr = [];
    var tblid = $("#comp tr");
    tblid.each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).find('td').find('span').attr('data-id'));
    });
    alert(arr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="comp">
  <tr>
    <td><span data-id="kiste"></span>kiste
      <p class="close">
        Same Name so please change
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span data-id="Futiste"></span>Futiste
      <p class="close">
        Same Name so please change
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span data-id="kavi"></span>kavi
      <p class="close">
        Same Name so please change
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span data-id="kiste"></span>kiste
      <p class="close">
        Same Name so please change
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span data-id="Futter"></span>Futter
      <p class="close">
        Same Name so please change
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
```

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305789/check-if-element-is-in-array-twice-time

Comment: Rory McCrossan: Already i have seen that link. but my question is different. How to get last duplicate value.I want to show error message only for last duplicate vlaue.

Comment: You can use the method exactly as outlined in that question: `if (countInArray(list, list.slice(-1).pop()) > 1)`

Comment: can u edit my jsfiddle?